# Laravel, Yajra Datatable, how to return if y then Yes else No

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatable

I have a column name show, in a country table, as now Im using yajra datatable so how can I view yes instead of y as well as , No if n

```
 $data = $this->SourceData->getData();
        return Datatables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()

->addColumn('Actions', function($data) {...})
                ->rawColumns(['Actions'])
                ->make(true);
```

jquery

```
       columns: [
            {data: 'id', name: 'id', visible:false},
            {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex'},
            {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
            {data: 'code', name: 'code'},
            {data: 'show', name: 'show'},
            {data: 'Actions', name: 'Actions',orderable:false,serachable:false,sClass:'text-center'},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `addColumn` as `show`

```
->addColumn('show', function($data) {
    if($data->show == 'y'){
        return 'Yes';
    }else{
        return 'No';
    }
})
```

Or else you can use `getAttribute` method in the model.

Add `getShowAttribute($value)`

```
function getShowAttribute($value){
    return  ($value == 'y') ? "Yes" : "No";
}
```

Comment: It is searchable. Yajra datatable search the return contain. and we're passing Yes and no in return.

Answer (score 4):

Please check this Code

```
$data = $this->SourceData->getData();

return Datatables::of($data)
        ->addIndexColumn()
        ->editColumn('show', function ($data) {
            return  ($data->show == 'y')?"Yes":($data->show == 'n')?"No":"";
        })
        ->addColumn('Actions', function($data) {...})
        ->rawColumns(['Actions'])
        ->make(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different approaches:
1. in jquery:

```
{
    data: function (data, type, row, meta) {
        if(data.show == 'y') {
            return 'YES';
        }
        return 'NO';
    name: 'show'
},
```

2. in yajra you can use editColumn